# Show that the simple extension $K(X)$ of $K$ has intermediate fields $K \varsubsetneqq F \varsubsetneqq K(X)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

> Show that the simple extension $K(X)$ of $K$ has intermediate fields $K \varsubsetneqq F \varsubsetneqq K(X)$.

I have tried this:

Suppose that $K \subseteq E \subseteq K(X)$. Let $\alpha \in K$ and $\beta \in E$, then there are $F(\alpha) \in K[X]$ and $G(\beta) \in E[Y]$ such that $K(\alpha) \in K[X]$ and $K(\beta) \in  E(Y)$, I don't see any progress with this. Any hint, please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do... But isn't $K\subset K(X^2)\subset K(X)$ a solution to your problem?

Comment: And hence you have, in fact, an extension series $K(X)=K_0\supsetneq K_1 \supsetneq K_2 \supsetneq \ldots \supsetneq K$ with $K_0\cong K_1\cong K_2\cong \ldots$.  You can also pick integers $n_1,n_2,\ldots >1$ as you like and demand that $\left[K_{i-1}:K_i\right]=n_i$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X\notin K$,

if $X^2\notin K$, then $K\subsetneq K(X^2)\subsetneq K(X)$.

If $X^2\in K$, then $X^3\notin K$. (Otherwise, if $X^3\in K$, then $X=\frac{X^3}{X^2}\in K$. $\Rightarrow \Leftarrow$.) Then, $K\subsetneq K(X^3)\subsetneq K(X)$.

Comment: It is not true that $K\left(X^3\right)\neq K(X)$.  For example, $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}^3\right)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (in fact, there is no intermediate filed $F$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\subsetneq F \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$).  I think the OP meant that $X$ is a transcendental element.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks!